# Quasar routes doesn't match login page

Tags: routes, quasar-framework

I'm trying out Quasar for the first time to build an SPA. I'm having a problem with the router. I already built a simple sign-in page in `src/pages/LoginPage.vue`, and then I added the appropriate route object to `src/router/routes.js`

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: () => import("pages/LoginPage.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout.vue"),
    children: [{ path: "", component: () => import("pages/IndexPage.vue") }],
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("pages/ErrorNotFound.vue"),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

I leave `src/router/index.js` the way it's generated by `quasar-cli`.

And then I try opening `http://localhost:9000/login` in the browser.

### Expected result

Page loads with `LoginPage` as the content. URL bar displays the intended address, or maybe an added trailing slash.

### Actual result

Address gets redirected to `http://localhost:9000/login#/` or `http://localhost:9000/login/#/`, depending on whether or not you put trailing slash when you type it in.

Page displays the `/` instead (`IndexPage` wrapped in `MainLayout`).

### Additional info

```
» Dev mode............... spa
» Pkg quasar............. v2.10.0
» Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.1.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think You need to change the `vueRouterMode`. So default it will be hash.

In `quasar.config.js`

Change it to history.

```
vueRouterMode: 'history'
```

Then if you hit http://localhost:9000/login it will just go to Login page and for http://localhost:9000/ it will open Index Page.

Answer (score 3):

- The default mode of Vue router is always **hash mode**, it appends a hash (#) to URL so that the page won’t be reloaded when the URL changes, it just rerenders the page instead of making requests to the server.
- I see in your code the direction for fallback routes:

```
...
// Always leave this as last one,
// but you can also remove it
{
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("pages/ErrorNotFound.vue"),
}
...
```

so you could be confident to use **history mode**. If entered URL doesn’t match any static assets uploaded to the server, then redirect to page ErrorNotFound.

In Quasar, this configuration is done inside file `quasar.config.js`, all you need to do is modify `vueRouterMode` property to `history` (default is `hash`)

- **FYI**:

  - [Different History modes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#different-history-modes)
  - [Configuring quasar.config.js](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/quasar-config-js)